# Applying Groovy extensions in Grails produces MissingMethodException for String#toBoolean()

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.2

### Background

Groovy have the feature of [adding methods to the existing classes](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Creating+an+extension+module), and I've found [some](https://github.com/timyates/groovy-common-extensions) [interesting](https://github.com/ataylor284/groovy-crypto-extensions) ones.

Then I [discovered](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/groovy-extension-module-and-grails-td4642249.html) that I need to customize my Grails bootstrap to load them, so I add:

```
def init = { servletContext -> addExtensionModules() }

  def addExtensionModules() {

    Map<CachedClass, List<MetaMethod>> map = [:]
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader
    try {
      Enumeration<URL> resources = classLoader.getResources(MetaClassRegistryImpl.MODULE_META_INF_FILE)
      for (URL url in resources) {
        if (url.path.contains('groovy-all')) {
          // already registered
          continue
        }
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        InputStream inStream
        try {
          inStream = url.openStream()
          properties.load(inStream)
          GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.registerExtensionModuleFromProperties(properties,
                            classLoader, map)
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
          throw new GroovyRuntimeException("Unable to load module META-INF descriptor", e)
        } finally {
          inStream?.close()
        }
      }
    }  catch (IOException ignored) {}
    map.each { CachedClass cls, List<MetaMethod> methods ->
    cls.setNewMopMethods(methods)
  }
}
```

And I add in my BuildConfig.groovy

```
compile ('ca.redtoad:groovy-crypto-extensions:0.2') {
  excludes 'groovy-all'
}
```

### The Question

The problem is that now I cannot use the `toBoolean()` method of Groovy String:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   java.lang.String.toBoolean() is applicable for argument types: ()
>   values: [] Possible solutions: asBoolean(), asBoolean(), toFloat(),
>   toDouble()

Since groovy is already registered, why the method is missing? I'm using Grails 2.2.4.

**EDIT**

Tested in a groovy 2.0.8 console, and the code works, so probably is something related to Grails.

```
@Grab('ca.redtoad:groovy-crypto-extensions:0.2')
@GrabExclude('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all')

addExtensionModules() //same method of BootStrap, ommited to make shorter.

def key = "password".toKey()
def ciphertext = "some plaintext".bytes.encrypt(key: key)
def x = new String(ciphertext.decrypt(key: key)).toBoolean()
println "S".toBoolean()
```

Comment: @dmahapatro A challenge to you, my friend :-)

Comment: Is there a bounty involved my dear friend? Kidding... Will look into it as soon as I am done with a meeting right now. ;)

Comment: question eligible for bounty in 2 days hehe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
map.each { CachedClass cls, List<MetaMethod> methods ->
    cls.setNewMopMethods(methods)
}
```

with

```
map.each { CachedClass cls, List<MetaMethod> methods ->
    //Add new MOP methods instead of set them as new
    cls.addNewMopMethods(methods) 
}
```

When new meta method is set in the `CachedClass` the existing extensions/meta methods are overriden by the only provided extension from the extension module. In this case, `groovy-crypto-extension` uses the below extension methods on String class

```
class java.lang.String=
[public static javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec ca.redtoad.groovy.extensions.crypto.CryptoExtensionMethods.toKey(java.lang.String), 
 public static javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec ca.redtoad.groovy.extensions.crypto.CryptoExtensionMethods.toKey(java.lang.String,java.util.Map)
]
```

If those methods are set to the CachedClass, the existing methods are wiped out. So it has to be replace with adding them to the CachedClass. Hence, making `toBoolean` available on String class.

Challenge accepted and executed. You owe me a treat. (Gift Card is acceptable too). ;)

Comment: Yeah dude, I owe you one! I started debugging `MetaClassRegistryImpl` but had to leave the office, and probably will spent more time to figure it out :-) Thanks!